# AttributeError: 'ElasticLoadBalancingv2' object has no attribute 'set_desired_capacity'

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-elb

```
import boto3
import json
import time
client = boto3.client('elbv2')
desired_capacity=8
client.set_desired_capacity(
    AutoScalingGroupName='Test-Web',
    DesiredCapacity=desired_capacity,
    HonorCooldown=True)
```

and 
boto3==1.7.1

When I run this script I get a

```
  File "deploy_staging_web.py", line 6, in <module>
    client.set_desired_capacity(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 601, in __getattr__
    self.__class__.__name__, item)
AttributeError: 'ElasticLoadBalancingv2' object has no attribute 'set_desired_capacity'
```

I intended to use python to scale aws instances up and down.

I'm not inside any virtual environment at the moment.

why is it being thrown, and how do I get across it?
It is even mentioned here  on the official documentation : https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/autoscaling.html#AutoScaling.Client.set_desired_capacity

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turns out to be a silly one.
boto3 has moved around the various functions.

set_desired_capacity is no longer part of 'elbv2' .
It is part of 'autoscaling' https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/autoscaling.html#AutoScaling.Client.set_desired_capacity

While 'describe_target_health' is still part of the former https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elbv2.html?highlight=elb#ElasticLoadBalancingv2.Client.describe_target_health.

Updating

> client = boto3.client('elbv2')

to

> client = boto3.client('autoscaling')

has solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The official document is for the latest version, not your too old version. Upgrade your `boto3` package to the latest. The most recent version is 1.9.243.

Comment: ```pip freeze
boto3==1.10.15
botocore==1.13.15
docutils==0.15.2
futures==3.3.0
jmespath==0.9.4
python-dateutil==2.8.0
s3transfer==0.2.1
six==1.13.0
urllib3==1.25.7
``` I have the latest version of the package installed.